# What methods are there for storing the order of items in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm creating a portfolio website that has galleries that contain images. I want the user of this portfolio to be able to order the images within a gallery. The problem itself is fairly simple I'm just struggling with deciding on a solution to implement.

There are 2 solutions I've thought of so far:

1. Simply adding an `order` column (or priority?) and then querying with an `ORDER BY` clause on that column. The disadvantage of this being that to change the order of a single image I'd have to update every single image in the gallery.
2. The second method would be to add 2 nullable columns `next` and `previous` that simply store the ID of the next and previous image. This would then mean there would be less data to update when the order was changed; however, it would be much more complex to set up and I'm not entirely sure how I'd actually implement it.

Extra options would be great.

- Are those options viable?
- Are there better options?
- How could / should they be implemented?

The current structure of the two tables in question is the following:

```
mysql> desc Gallery;

+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| title        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| subtitle     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| description  | varchar(5000)    | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| date         | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| isActive     | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| lastModified | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+

mysql> desc Image;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| galleryId    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| description  | varchar(250)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| path         | varchar(250)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| lastModified | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Currently there is no implementation of ordering in any form.

Comment: Order them based on what?

Comment: User preference, so say the user uploads 5 images, they will then have the option to order them once they're uploaded. If they wanted the last picture they uploaded to be the first one that's seen, that's the kind of situation I'm thinking of.

Comment: You're pretty much asking about Order Topologies. Left/Right is pretty common when you need to be very specific about your sub-items in a tree. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology#Left_and_right_order_topologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while 1 is a bit ugly you can do:

```
  UPDATE table set order=order+1 where order>='orderValueOfItemYouCareAbout';
```

this will update all the rest of the images and you wont have to do a ton of leg work.

Comment: Would this work more along these sorts of lines: `UPDATE Image AS i SET order = order + 1 INNER JOIN Gallery AS g ON g.id = i.galleryId WHERE order >= x AND g.id = y;`? x being current order and y being the g.gallery ID for the gallery the images are in?

Comment: I suppose so, I have no few of your db structure or table entries, but assuming you have a table of images with separate gallery ids then this could work.

Comment: I'll post the two tables in question in my question.

Comment: I have opted for an alternative solution to this which I think makes more sense for my current situation. I'll be posting it as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

As bart2puck has said and I stated in the question, option 1 is a little bit ugly; it is however the option I have chosen to go with to simplify the solution all round.

I have added a column (`displayOrder int UNSIGNED`) to the Image table after `path`. When I want to re-order a row in the table I simply swap rows around. So, if I have 3 rows:

```
mysql> SELECT id, galleryId, description, displayOrder FROM Image ORDER BY displayOrder;
+-----+-----------+----------------------------------+--------------+
| id  | galleryId | description                      | displayOrder |
+-----+-----------+----------------------------------+--------------+
| 271 |        20 | NULL                             |            1 |
| 270 |        20 | Tracks leading into the ocean... |            2 |
| 278 |        20 | NULL                             |            3 |
+-----+-----------+----------------------------------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I want to re-order row 278 to appear second rather than third, I'll simply swap it with the second by doing the following:

```
UPDATE Image SET displayOrder =   
  CASE displayOrder     
    WHEN 2 THEN 3
    WHEN 3 THEN 2
  END 
WHERE galleryId = 20 
AND displayOrder BETWEEN 2 AND 3;
```

Resulting in:

```
mysql> SELECT id, galleryId, description, displayOrder FROM Image ORDER BY displayOrder;
+-----+-----------+----------------------------------+--------------+
| id  | galleryId | description                      | displayOrder |
+-----+-----------+----------------------------------+--------------+
| 271 |        20 | NULL                             |            1 |
| 278 |        20 | NULL                             |            2 |
| 270 |        20 | Tracks leading into the ocean... |            3 |
+-----+-----------+----------------------------------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

One possible issue that some people may find is that you can only alter the position by one place with this method, i.e. to move image 278 to appear first I'd have to make it second, then first, otherwise the current first image would appear third.